# How to start ALL processors

Tags: apache-nifi

I have NiFi running on a test environment and would like it to automatically start all processors as the last step of deployment.

Do I need to parse all the processor ids and hit the /nifi-api/processors endpoint for each one or is it possible to start all - eg from the /nifi-api/process-groups endpoint ?

My NiFi flow has uuid 66f83c1d-0162-1000-baff-01e60296540a - this GET curl statement returns information successfully:

```
curl -i -X GET http://localhost:9090/nifi-api/process-groups/66f83c1d-0162-1000-baff-01e60296540a
```

However trying to PUT a status fails:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"status":"RUNNING"}' http://localhost:9090/nifi-api/process-groups/66f83c1d-0162-1000-baff-01e60296540a
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 06 Aug 2018 11:08:15 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/plain
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 429
Server: Jetty(9.4.3.v20170317)

Cannot construct instance of `org.apache.nifi.web.api.dto.status.ProcessGroupStatusDTO` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('RUNNING')
 at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: org.apache.nifi.web.api.entity.ProcessGroupEntity["status"])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes** by using NiFi RestApi we can **start all processors** in a processor group.

As you are missing **id** key value in your json,

> {**"id":"66f83c1d-0162-1000-baff-01e60296540a"**,"state":"RUNNING"}

we need to mention **state** not **status** to run/stop processors in the group

> {"id":"66f83c1d-0162-1000-baff-01e60296540a",**"state":"RUNNING"**}

and we need to include **flow** in the address of the rest api.

> http://localhost:9090/nifi-api **/flow/** process-groups/66f83c1d-0162-1000-baff-01e60296540a

Try with below Curl command

```
curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"id":"66f83c1d-0162-1000-baff-01e60296540a","state":"RUNNING"}' http://localhost:9090/nifi-api/flow/process-groups/66f83c1d-0162-1000-baff-01e60296540a
```

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/110096/start-process-group-using-nifi-rest-api.html) for more details regarding start process group using RestAPI.

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Does it start all the nested process groups as well?